# iPython - set up magic commands in configuration file

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I use iPython mostly via notebooks but also in the terminal. I just created my default profile by running `ipython profile create`.

I can't seem to figure out how to have the profile run several magic commands that I use every time. I tried to look this up online and in a book I'm reading but can't get it to work. For example, if I want `%debug` activated for every new notebook I tried adding these lines to my config file:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['debug']
```

or

```
c.TerminalPythonApp.extensions = ['debug']
```

and I either get import errors or nothing. My (closely related) questions are the following:

1. What line to do I add to my ipython config file to activate magic commands? Some require parameters, e.g. `%reload_ext autoreload` and `%autoreload 2`. How do I also pass these parameters in the config file?
2. Can I separate which get added for terminal vs. notebooks in a single config file or must I set up separate profiles if I want different magic's activated? (e.g., `matplotlib` inline or not). Do the two lines above affect notebooks vs. terminal settings (i.e., `c.InteractiveShellApp` vs. `c.TerminalPythonApp`)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Execute magics as follows:

```
get_ipython().magic(u"%reload_ext autoreload")
get_ipython().magic(u"%autoreload 2")
```

You can put those lines in your startup script here:

```
~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/00-first.py
```

*Update*: as of IPython v0.13, the [`run_line_magic`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.interactiveshell.html#IPython.core.interactiveshell.InteractiveShell.run_line_magic) function should be used instead of the [`magic`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.interactiveshell.html#IPython.core.interactiveshell.InteractiveShell.magic) function with:

```py
get_ipython().run_line_magic("reload_ext", "autoreload")
get_ipython().run_line_magic("autoreload", "2")
```

otherwise you get a deprecation warning.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Especially the `autoreload` magic :D

Answer (score 1):

To start for example the %pylab magic command on startup do the following:

```
ipython profile create pylab
```

Add the following code to your .ipython\profile_pylab\ipython_config.py

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%pylab']
```

and start ipython

```
ipython --profile=pylab
```