# Autocompletion on IPython + matplotlib leads 'RuntimeError: main thread not in main loop'

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, ipython, tk-toolkit

I am plotting some data using Ipython3 with the default matplotlib backend 'TKAgg' with an virtualenv. I have a plot_script that plots my data showing it in a new window and it works for some time. Then somewhat randomly it throws me out with the error message seen in the linked picture when I use tab to autocomplete a statement. When I use Agg backend it works off course but that becomes very tedious since I need to examine the data (zoom in etc.).

[Screenshot of the Ipython Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGfjk.png)

I realize that I am probably not understanding how threads work but shouldn't there be a way to get a GUI-Window while using a functions in an plot_script that are very straightforward. Basically, I am just calling the function with plot_script.plot_something(pd.DataFrame) and the plot is diplayed:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plot_something(data):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
    .... # Plot something
    fig.savefig()     
    plt.show()

    plt.close(fig)
    fig.clear()
```

How do I move my plotting to the main loop and is this a problem with ipython?

Answer (score 2):

You likely need to activate the correct matplotlib & tk eventloop. This can be done using the [`%gui` magic](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-gui) with `%gui tk` in the general case, and in the case of matplotlib, some extra setup is done via the [`%matplotlib` magic](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-matplotlib), likely in your case using `%matplotlib tk`.

There are a number of other libraries that can trigger this kind of issue where there is not answer yet, in particular using OpenCV with terminal IPython can make the main thread panic, but not in a reproducible manner, not debugged and fixed yet.

If using the magics does not fix it, please feel free to open a bug on the IPython tracker.

Comment: Thanks for help. So now I use '%gui tk' and '%matplotlib tk' at startup. Have to get used to the different behavior ;). If I don't notice the error until the end of the week or if you second remark is correct, I will accept your answer.

Comment: No worries, happy to be of any help. Tip: sign up for other stack-exchange site, they give you 100 rep if you sign-in to enough of them.

Comment: Now the pyplot.show() function is not needed anymore since a window is opened at every pyplot.plot(data), right?! Is there a way to suppress the plot window to just plot to a file and not get the windows everytime.

Comment: Arr same error showed up again. I am going to post a report.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll do my best to also help you on the bugtracker.

Comment: Yeah, this seemed to fix it for a bit but then the same error came back up.

Comment: I recommend including these in a startup script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32683001/4549682
Typing it out every time is no fun.